# Issue extracting data using BS4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract some data from a website using bs4 however I can't access the exact text that I need. Using the following code

```
name = (soup('td', {'class':'mstat'}))
```

outputs

```
[<td class="mstat" colspan="3"><span class="r">badges</span></td>]
```

However I need class "r". If I try to access class "r" using the following code I just get an empty list returned []

```
name = (soup('td', {'class':'r'}))
```

output

```
[]
```

I would like to get the text which reads 'badges', the text can change length and be different so I can't just delete the surrounding code.

desired output

```
'badges'
```

Would anyone know what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: Shouldn't you search for `'span', class_='r'` instead od `td`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a `<span>` tag instead:

```
soup('span', class_='r')
```

If you want to only find `span` tags with that class inside of `td` tags with the `mstat` class you'll need to loop:

```
spans = []
for td in soup('td', class_='mstat'):
    spans.expand(td('span', class_='r'))
```